# Ajax Form Submit Error/Success handler

Tags: jquery, ajax

This Ajax Code did worked fine for submitting but shows `done` as response instead of `Success` which I assigned. Take a look and please help me about what's wrong here:

```
<script>
    var dataString = 'something';
    var response = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "process.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function() 
                    {
                        $("#form_status").html('Sending Data...');

                    },
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        if(response == "done"){
                        $("#form_status").hide().fadeIn('slow').html('Success!');
                        }

                        else {
                            $("#form_status").hide().fadeIn('fast').html(response);
                        }
                    }

                });
                 response.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {

                    $("#form_status").html('Error Submitting Data!');
                }); 
</script>
```

P.S: Please Explain your edits. I am new to Ajax & JavaScript.

Comment: The response you're getting is the result of the ´process.php´, could you please add the code on that file as well

Comment: Yes, I know the result I was getting. I get `done` as result while according to my code up there the `#form_status` should have `success` shown not `done`.

Comment: Just curious, have you double-checked your response to make sure the results are spelled out as `done` without spaces? What if a space snuck up in there resulting in `done    ` with a space?

Comment: I have triple checked it! I did checked by putting `done` text only in that file.

Comment: And Now My whole site started dis-functioning as above.